# Centering image and also offsetting it

Tags: css

I'm trying to overlay this logo so it sits at the bottom of the page, and also so it is offset by its full width to the left (so that the *right edge* of the logo sits against the *center line*).

If I use `position:absolute` on `#logo` I have access to the `top` and `left` properties, which is good, but now centering won't work...

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygore/4xmutpnt/)

Also: making it a fixed distance from the left edge of the page won't work because the page is responsive. The right edge of the logo always has to sit perfectly on the center line.

In case the fiddle isn't working here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id ="layer1">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="layer2">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxpG.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1a1a1a 50%, #f15922 50%);
}
#layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
}
#logo {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
```

Comment: All I see in the fiddle is a background color style on body.  It's best to post all the code in the question also, even with fiddle.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't explain the same as you explained in the post. In short: It is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the image positioned offset perfectly at all widths, we need to get rid of the gradient and **apply the second background to a pseudo element of the body**.

In these 2 examples, body provides the orange background and `body:before` provides the dark background.

### Example 1 - logo is a background image

`calc(50% - 167px)` offsets the logo.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #f15922 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxpG.png) calc(50% - 167px) bottom no-repeat;
}
body:before {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

### Example 2 - logo is `<img>`

`right: 50%` and `bottom: 0` keep it at the bottom and offset by the natural width of the image.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #f15922;
}
body:before {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxpG.png" />
```

### Old Archived Examples (with gradient)

**Limitation:** There is a gap at certain viewport widths that is caused by the gradients 50% calculation. I'm not certain that this can be avoided.

### Archived 1 - Keep it all in a background image / gradient

`calc(50% - 167px)` offsets the image from the center

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxpG.png) calc(50% - 167px) bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(to left, #1a1a1a 50%, #f15922 50%);
}
```

### Archived 2 - Using `<img>`

`right: 50%` and `bottom: 0` keep it at the bottom and offset by the natural width of the image.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #1a1a1a 50%, #f15922 50%);
}
#logo {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxpG.png" />
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm going to try this because you're right: the logo is not always positioning correctly, perhaps due to the gradients 50% calculation, as you've said. Question: what do you mean by "Archived" in your response?

Comment: I don't want to remove my old examples, so I put "Archived" as a heading. Sometimes they might be useful to others in the future.

Comment: I've removed the linear-gradient and added the pseudo element, as per your suggestion. That works much better, as the linear-gradient didn't display correctly in Chrome (well it appeared to, but the logo wouldn't sit exactly on the center line. Interestingly it was fine in Firefox).

Comment: @anthonygore - Yes, it looks like Chrome has a buggy linear-gradient. It is choppy when resizing the page to different widths and it calculates gradient percentages differently. It does mean that in the future it should be fixed. Maybe :)

Comment: Also, it may be better to use `position: fixed` with z-index to place your background elements underneath your content. This will prevent them from being affected by scrolling. [This is an example for you](http://jsbin.com/qumisi/2/edit)

Answer (score 3):

You could add `position: absolute;` and `transform` to center your `#logo` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v0gobtuc/)**

```
#logo {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but I believe that the OP wants it to be `translateX(-100%)`. Also note that browser prefixes are needed for older browsers

Comment: Actually, what I'm after, is for the right edge of the logo to be against the center line (i.e. the line determined by the background linear-gradient)

Comment: I think there's no point in the `#wrapper` div now either. But yeah, you've nailed it. Thanks.

Comment: Mary Melody, I'm sorry to rescind my acceptance of your answer. Even though it worked within the constraints of the question I posed, I think @misterManSam's answer is more complete because it addressed the flaw in the way I was rendering the background colours.